# CFG and closure properties

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am solving one problem and I urgently need a hint to solve one problem:

> Use closure under union to show that the following language is context-free
>   $$\left\{a^mb^nc^pd^q : n=q,\ \text{or}\;\ m\leq p\ \;\text{or}\;\ m+n=p+q\right\}$$

EDIT:
I study the closure properties of context-free languages. It was said there that CFG are closed under union.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site I point you [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: thanks, I will obey to the rules

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Your language is clearly the union of the following three languages:

$$\begin{align*}
L_1&=\left\{a^mb^nc^pd^q:n=q\right\}\\
L_2&=\left\{a^mb^nc^pd^q:m\le p\right\}\\
L_3&=\left\{a^mb^nc^pd^q:m+n=p+q\right\}
\end{align*}$$

Can you show that each of these languages is context-free, either directly by writing context-free grammars for them or indirectly by using known context-free languages and preservation properties?

Comment: yes i see now, thanks

Comment: @nuraureum: You’re welcome.